# Error in triggering mail using web activity in Azure data factory

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-data-factory

I am trying to setup mail notification in event of copy activity fails(using For logic apps). Unfortunately I am getting the below error, however when I do the same (copy --> web activity) outside foreach activity, works fine and mail gets triggered in the event of failure.

**Error Message from Web Activity:**

> "message": "The expression 'activity('Copy SQL to Blob').Error.message' cannot be evaluated because property 'Error' cannot be selected.

**Screenshot from adf:**
[image]

**Body details of web activity:**

```
{"DataFactoryName":"@{pipeline().DataFactory}","PipelineName":"@{pipeline().Pipeline}","Subject":"Data Load: @{pipeline().Pipeline} An Error has occurred!!","ErrorMessage":"@{activity('Copy SQL to Blob').Error.message}","Activity Name": "Copy Activity","EmailTo":"user@domain.com"}
```

**Error Message from Copy Activity:**

[image]
Like said above, the same web activity works fine outside the iterator. Any inputs greatly appreciated?

Comment: Interesting problem - I've never tried to do this, but my first inclination is to try either @{activity('Copy SQL to Blob').output.Error.message} or @{activity('Copy SQL to Blob').errors[0].message}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When i want to catch the error from a copy activity i always use the expression:
@activity('Copy Data').output.errors[0].message and that works fine even in a loop

Comment: Thanks Joel & Koen errors[0] did the trick. Many thanks for your inputs here.